# cannot display a table of data received from an ajax request in asp. net web api

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui

I am trying to display a table of data returned by the following restful web api service  accessible by this url. The problem is it displays only the header of the table and not the content.

> /SMART/api/Build/GetAll

This url will return as output an IList of object called release, I have already tested this. The release object is structured as follows.

```
 [Table("releases")]
    public class Release
    {

        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [StringLength(10)]
        [Column("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [StringLength(10)]
        [Column("Type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [Column("to_be_displayed")]
        public bool ToBeDisplayed { get; set; }

    }
```

Here is my javascript code

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/SMART/api/Build/GetAll',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
        // Get the JSON Data
        var Data = new kendo.data.DataSource({

            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "release.id",
                    fields: {
                        id: { type: "string" },
                        Name: { type: "string" },
                        Type : {type : "string"},
                        ToBeDisplayed: { type: "boolean" },


                    }
                }
            }
        });
        //Create a tab for the wip release



        $('#listGrid').kendoGrid({
            scrollable: false,
            sortable: true,
            resizable: true,
            filterable: true,
            autoSync: true,
            dataSource: Data,
            columns: [
            { field: "release.id", title: "Id" },
            { field: "release.Name", title: "Name" },
            { field: "release.ToBeDisplayed", title: "To be displayed", template: "<input name='ToBeDisplayed' type='checkbox' data-bind='checked: ToBeDisplayed' #= ToBeDisplayed ? checked='checked' : '' # class='build-tobedisplayed-checkbox'/>" },

            ]
        });
    }
});
```

Here is my cshtml code

```
<div id="listGrid" class="k-grid-content">
    <div class="k-loading-mask" style="width:100%;height:100%"><span class="k-loading-text">Loading...</span><div class="k-loading-image"><div class="k-loading-color"></div></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm no kendo UI expert, but it's evident that your `data` variable is never assigned to anything. How could you show it in your grid if you do not assign it inside your `DataSource`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following Code:

```
function definitionUserGrid() {

var baseUrl = '/SMART/api/Build/GetAll';
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: baseUrl,
            dataType: "json"
        },
        parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
            if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                return {
                    models: kendo.stringify(options.models)
                };
            }
        }
    },
    batch: true,
    pageSize: 15
});

$("#listGrid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    pageable: true,
    reorderable: true,
    resizable: true,
    sortable: true,
    filterable: {
        mode: "row"
    },
    columns: [
    {field: "Id",
        title: "Id",
    }, {
        filterable: {
            cell: {
                enabled: true,
                showOperators: false,
                operator: "contains"
            }
        },
        field: "Name",
        title: "Name"
    }, {
        filterable: {
            cell: {
                enabled: true,
                showOperators: false,
                operator: "contains"
            }
        },
        field: "ToBeDisplayed",
        title: "To be displayed",
        template: "<input name='ToBeDisplayed' type='checkbox' data-bind='checked: ToBeDisplayed' #= ToBeDisplayed ? checked='checked' : '' # class='build-tobedisplayed-checkbox'/>" },
    }]
});

}
```

And finally:

call function definitionUserGrid()

```
$(function(){
    definitionUserGrid();
});
```